# Fluent NHibernate HasMany collection not populating

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, collections, fluent-nhibernate, has-many

I am having trouble setting up a Fluent NHibernate HasMany collection.

I have set the code up as below and I'm calling it via Linq IQueryable.
In SQL Profiler, I can see the correct SQL getting called, but the Store.Staff collection is always empty.

```
    public class Store
    {
        public virtual IList<Employee> Staff { get; set; }

        public virtual void AddEmployee(Employee Employee)
        {
            Employee.Store = this;
            if(Staff == null)
                Staff = new List<Employee>();
            Staff.Add(Employee);
        }


    public class StoreMap : ClassMap<Store>
    {
        public StoreMap()
        {
            Id(x => x.StoreId)
                .GeneratedBy.Identity();

            HasMany(x => x.Staff)
                  .Inverse()
                  .Cascade.All();            
       ...
        }
    }


    public bool Create(Store entity)
    {
        var stores = _readRepository.Query<Store>()
            .Where(x => x.StoreId == entity.StoreId)
            .Fetch(x => x.Staff)
            .ToList();



select store0_.StoreId, 
       staff2_.SurgeryId,
       staff2_.StoreId  
from   dbo.[Store] store0_
       left outer join dbo.[Employee] staff2_
         on store0_.StoreId = staff2_.StoreId
where  store0_.StoreId = 1 /* @p0 */
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was confusing two parts of the framework. I was using Linq to retrieve the data and couldn't eagerly load.
Instead of using Linq, I now use NHibernate.Session.QueryOver.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this is the problem, but you should be using FetchMany to eagerly load collections, not Fetch.